# How Do I copy/paste/clear value

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what I’m working with but can’t figure out where I’m going wrong.

I have been reviewing numerous posts but just can't find answers.

```
Sub copypasteclearDATA()
Sheet6.Select
Dim Name_ As String
Dim Eval As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 23 To 35
    If Cells(i, 32) = "True" Then
        Name = Sheet6.Cells(i, 1)
        Eval = Sheet6.Cells(i, 29)
        Sheet8.Activate
        eRow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Sheet8.Cells(eRow, 1) = Cells(i, 1)
        Sheet8.Cells(eRow, 2) = Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet6.Activate
     End If
Next i
End If
```

'Formula here to delete data once copied to sheet1 without deleting 'formulas in Column AC.
End Sub

I want to basically copy the 2 cells on sheet 1 and paste them on sheet 2 then clear the entire rows on sheet 1 that held True keeping formulas intact.

Comment: If Sheet 1, Column AF = True, Click command button to copy and paste Cell A23 and Cell AC23 to Sheet 2, Cell A5 and Cell B6. Then clear content on Sheet1, in Cells A:Z of the row that held True, but keep formulas in place. 
I need this to work for 13 rows where column AF = True.

Comment: You've got one `If` and two `End If`'s. Where's one more `If`? And make indentations for readability.